# Cannot use "git commit -a"

Tags: git

Yesterday I set up a new machine to develop with, which makes me think I probably missed one step somewhere because when I run:

```
$ git commit -a
```

I get the following:

```
error: cannot run : No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor ''.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of **echo $EDITOR** ?

Comment: Set the environment variable `EDITOR` to something meaningful, e.g. to `gedit` or `emacsclient` or `vim` ....

Comment: I actually solved it with `$ git config --global core.editor vim`, forgot to configure the git editor. Sorry for any inconvenience and thank you all for the fast response.

Comment: alternatively you could use git commit -am "<comment>"

Comment: Write your solution in an answer and accept it.

Comment: This is strange, `git` should fall back to something sane if none of the environment variables giving the editor (GIT_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are checked in that order) are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I forgot to configure the git editor, this is how I did it for vim.

```
$ git config --global core.editor vim
```